# Reading sections in app.config issue

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I have my app.config broken into sections like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="databaseConnectionStrings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="dataDictionary" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <databaseConnectionStrings>
    <add key="ILFSsqlServer" value="ODBC;DSN=sql server copycloas;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=ILFSView;"/>
  </databaseConnectionStrings>
  <dataDictionary>
    <add key="CLOASEUCDBA_T_CONTACT" value="CLOASEUCDBA.T_Contact" />
  </dataDictionary>
</configuration>
```

From what I can tell the xml should work fine but when I try calling it using:

```
var section2 = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataDictionary") as NameValueConfigurationCollection;
var result2 = section2["CLOASEUCDBA_T_CONTACT"];
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

I get a null reference exception of the on the second line. Im not sure why it shouldn't be null...

Comment: You entitled the question as "Solved", does this mean that you found out what was wrong? If so, please either accepte my answer, or write your own if my answer didn't help. =) This shall help other community members to find related solutions to similar problems.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the answer from it since you created a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using `NameValueCollection` instead of `NameValueConfigurationCollection`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to type cast to [**AppSettingsSection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [**NameValueCollection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx).

> From MSDN : [**ConfigurationManager.GetSection Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Create the AppSettings section. 
// The function uses the GetSection(string)method  
// to access the configuration section.  
// It also adds a new element to the section collection. 
public static void CreateAppSettings() {
    // Get the application configuration file.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
            ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    string sectionName = "appSettings";

    // Add an entry to appSettings. 
    int appStgCnt =
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count;
    string newKey = "NewKey" + appStgCnt.ToString();

    string newValue = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " 
                          + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(newKey, newValue);

    // Save the configuration file.
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    // Force a reload of the changed section. This  
    // makes the new values available for reading.
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);

    // Get the AppSettings section.
    AppSettingsSection appSettingSection =
        (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection(sectionName);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Using GetSection(string).");
    Console.WriteLine("AppSettings section:");
    Console.WriteLine(
    appSettingSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml());
}
```

**Notice** the `config.GetSection()` method call just before the `Console.WriteLine()`.

Another way that I use often is by accessing the project properties as follows.

```
using Namespace.Properties;

public class MyClass {
    public string MySettingMeaningfulName { 
        get { return Settings.Default.ClOASEUCDBA_T_CONTACT; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something here but is this just creating the app.config at runtime and its not being saved?

Comment: It is saved. See the line: "// Save the configuration file.", followed by `config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMethod.Modified);`?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're casting `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataDictionary")` to `NameValueConfigurationCollection`. Change the casting to `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`.

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_NameValueConfigurationSection()
    {
        var section2 = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataDictionary") as NameValueCollection;
        var result2 = section2["CLOASEUCDBA_T_CONTACT"];

        Assert.AreEqual("CLOASEUCDBA.T_Contact", result2);
    }
```